# Problems upgrading to MimeKit 2.4.0

Tags: c#, mime, mimekit

I am trying to upgrade MimeKit from an older version (2.0.7) to a newer version 2.4.0 but I am having some issues. After upgrading some of my tests from the project are throwing an exception in MimeIterator

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' from assembly 'mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I found some similar errors regarding the .NET Framework but nothing helped me. The app curently target .NET Framework 4.7.2

Downgrading back to MimeKit 2.0.7 fixes the problem, so it's related to the newer version.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with MimeKit 2.4.0.1

Comment: I can't reproduce with MimeKit 2.4.0, either. I tried on both Mac (using Mono) and Windows.

Comment: I just released MimeKit 2.4.1 built on Windows (2.4.0 and 2.4.0.1 were built on Mac/Mono), so maybe that will fix this issue for you.

Comment: Did something change from 2.0.7 to 2.4.0 in the .NET Framework ? I think the documentation shows just the current .NET Framework

Comment: Nothing changed in MimeKit's code wrt MimeIterator.